# How does x =new int[2]; work in this java code?

Tags: java, arrays

Analyze the following code:

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        int[] y = x;

        x = new int[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(y[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

- A. The program displays 1 2 3 4
- B. The program displays 0 0
- C. The program displays 0 0 3 4
- D. The program displays 0 0 0 0

The answer for the following code is A. But why the answer is not B ?

Comment: `x` and `y` are *references*.

Comment: because you are printing the values of: {1,2,3,4}. How could the answer possibly be anything but A?

Comment: because after assigning initial value of x to y then only you have changed the value of x which means it won`t affect the current value of y now. So when you print out y then it prints the value which corresponds to the previous value of x

Comment: I think it would be better to post text instead of image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's assume that `{1, 2, 3, 4}` has memory address `M`.

When assigning `x` to `{1, 2, 3, 4}`, you're assigning a reference to the memory address of `{1, 2, 3, 4}`, i.e. `x` will *point* to `M`.

When assigning `y = x`, then `y` will refer `M`.

After that, you're changing the reference where `x` points to, let's say it's `N`.

So, when printing, `y` points to `M` (which is the address of `{1, 2, 3, 4}`), but `x` holds reference to `N` (which is `new int[2]`). And here comes the difference.

Answer (score 4):

To give you a more clear explanation:

```
int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4};       // step 1
```

---

[image]

---

```
int[] y = x;    // step 2
```

---

[image]

---

```
 x = new int[2];        // step 3
```

---

[image]

---

In the third step, when the `x` changes, `y` is not affected because you are changing the reference of `x`, not the address of the array. So it doesn't affect the value of `y`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `int[] y = x;` the array `y` will have some variables like this: `{1,2,3,4}`.

This line `x = new int[2];` will creating a different space for x pointing to it.

So the result will be `{1,2,3,4}` of the array `y`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is definitely A. I will explain it a little bit more step by step:

```
int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int[] y = x;
```

From the above lines, we now know that x and y are equal to each other in values and their length is 4.

```
x = new int[2];
```

We have now changed the value of x, but we haven't changed the value of y.

So now x has a length of 2 which is {0, 0}, and y still has a length of 4 which is {1, 2, 3, 4}, and here comes the difference...

```
for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++)
```

In the above line, we already know that **y.length = 4**, so it's **i < 4**.

```
System.out.print(y[i] + " ");
```

The above line will now print the array of values of y respectively which are:

1

2

3

4

Answer (score 1):

Because You are assigning the value of x to y not giving reference of x to y.